# Using Regex to get all users after "Users:"

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file in this format.

```
Users:
      user1
      user2
Groups:
      group1
      group2
```

I am trying to get the users (user1 and user2) from this list by using this pattern:

```
userRegex = 'Users:\n(\s+\S+\n)*'
users = re.search(userRegex, groupInfo)
```

But the list is empty, what am I missing here?

Comment: When you quantify a capture group, it matches all the repetitions, but only captures the last occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
groupInfo = """Users:
      user1
      user2
Groups:
      group1
      group2"""

match = re.search(r'Users:\s*(.*?)(?=\nGroups:)', groupInfo, re.S)
if match:
    print(match.group(1).split())
```

See [proof](https://tio.run/##TY4xC8MgEIV3f4W45AxBMN0KIWPoXLplCcFUoVE5zdBfb40pITfdu3vvu/PfqJ29pWRW7zBSVOSNbvMPuzjaUcbYKygMd0JLbVnIS9@SYXef@5KVV9FmBCHrFGedeahEUBPOGrA6wGOoQdQ9h74b7R/Gq4aeXzR76MmJWWihHKc8GhuhDESxguQi@I@JwHlKPw).

**Result**: `['user1', 'user2']`.

**Regex explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Users:                   'Users:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Groups:                  'Groups:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: I would change the regex to `r'Users:\s*(.*?)(?=\n\S+|$)'`  in case groups and user sections are in different orders.

Comment: I tried your solution but it's not working? I am learning Regex as well right now. https://regex101.com/r/rlw1Ml/1/

Comment: @KamranPervaiz You did not enable `re.S` or `re.DOTALL`, this is right - https://regex101.com/r/rlw1Ml/2

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a Perforce group spec -- if you use P4Python, when you fetch a group it automatically parses the spec into a Python object so there's no need for regex shenanigans.

```
from P4 import P4

p4 = P4()

p4.connect()
group = p4.fetch_group("mygroup")
users = group['Users']
subgroups = group['Groups']
p4.disconnect()
```